UltiSnips "invalid line" in snippet file
I was using coc.nvim for a while, and was very happy with the performance/function, but I am not a huge fan of the JavaScript dependency, so I wanted to give UltiSnips a chance. I have installed everything, and it is (mostly) working. For now, I am only working with LaTeX and .tex files with TexLab as a LS.
When I first open Neovim and load a .tex file, everything appears fine. I can browse around and everything works. I press i to enter insert mode, and everything is normal. However, as soon as I try to type anything, as soon as I type the first character, I get the following error:
Ultisnips Error:

Invalid line '\\section{$1}' in ~/.config/nvim/snippets/tex.snippets:2

I have no idea what is wrong with my snippets file. The really strange thing is that all my snippets function. They expand as they should (automatically/manually according to the options I specified). The only thing that does NOT work is tab stops. NONE of the tab stops I specified anywhere in my snippet file work. If I press tab it just adds a tab (4 spaces) regardless of whether or not I specified a tab stop there.
Here is my snippet file:
snippet sb "bulleted list" A
\section{$1}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item $2
    \end{itemize} $0
endsnippet

snippet it "italics"
\textit{$1}$0
endsnippet

snippet itm "itemize list"
\begin{itemize}
    \item
\end{itemize}
endsnippet

snippet enu "enumerate list"
\begin{enumerate}
    \item $1
\end{enumerate}
endsnippet

snippet i "new list item"
\item $1
endsnippet

snippet sec "new section"
\section{$1}
$0
endsnippet

snippet bf "bold font"
\textbf{$1}$0
endsnippet

and here is my config (I'm a 1 giant file guy):
-- Bootstrap lazy.nvim
local lazypath = vim.fn.stdpath("data") .. "/lazy/lazy.nvim"
if not (vim.uv or vim.loop).fs_stat(lazypath) then
  local lazyrepo = "https://github.com/folke/lazy.nvim.git"
  local out = vim.fn.system({ "git", "clone", "--filter=blob:none", "--branch=stable", lazyrepo, lazypath })
  if vim.v.shell_error ~= 0 then
    vim.api.nvim_echo({
      { "Failed to clone lazy.nvim:\n", "ErrorMsg" },
      { out, "WarningMsg" },
      { "\nPress any key to exit..." },
    }, true, {})
    vim.fn.getchar()
    os.exit(1)
  end
end
vim.opt.rtp:prepend(lazypath)

-- Make sure to setup `mapleader` and `maplocalleader` before
-- loading lazy.nvim so that mappings are correct.
-- This is also a good place to setup other settings (vim.opt)
vim.g.mapleader = " "
vim.g.maplocalleader = "\\"

-- Basic settings
vim.o.number = true -- Enable line numbers
vim.o.relativenumber = true -- Enable relative line numbers
vim.o.tabstop = 4 -- Number of spaces a tab represents
vim.o.shiftwidth = 4 -- Number of spaces for each indentation
vim.o.expandtab = true -- Convert tabs to spaces
vim.o.smartindent = true -- Automatically indent new lines
vim.o.wrap = true -- Disable line wrapping
vim.o.cursorline = true -- Highlight the current line
vim.o.termguicolors = true -- Enable 24-bit RGB colors

-- Syntax highlighting and filetype plugins
vim.cmd('syntax enable')
vim.cmd('filetype plugin indent on')

-- Setup lazy.nvim
require("lazy").setup({
  spec = {
    -- add your plugins here
    -- ----------------------------------------------------------------------colorscheme \/
--{"cocopon/iceberg.vim", lazy = false, priority = 1000},

    { "bluz71/vim-moonfly-colors", name = "moonfly", lazy = false, priority = 1000 },


--{"cdmill/neomodern.nvim",
--  lazy = false,
--  priority = 1000,
-- config = function()
--    require("neomodern").setup({
      -- optional configuration here
--  style = "iceclimber"
            --iceclimber
            --coffeecat
            --darkforest
            --campfire
            --roseprime
            --daylight
--    })
--    require("neomodern").load()
--  end,},
------------------------------------------------------------------------------vimtex \/
  {"lervag/vimtex",
  lazy = false,     -- we don't want to lazy load VimTeX
  init = function()
    -- VimTeX configuration goes here, e.g.
    vim.g.vimtex_view_general_viewer = "okular"
  end},
------------------------------------------------------------------------------lightline \/
{"itchyny/lightline.vim"},
------------------------------------------------------------------------------nvim-cmp \/
{"yioneko/nvim-cmp",
    branch = "perf",
    event = "InsertEnter",
    opts = function()
        local cmp = require "cmp"
    end,
    dependencies ={
        "hrsh7th/cmp-nvim-lsp",
        "hrsh7th/cmp-buffer",
        "hrsh7th/cmp-path",
        "quangnguyen30192/cmp-nvim-ultisnips",},
    },
------------------------------------------------------------------------------ultisnips \/
{"sirver/ultisnips"},
------------------------------------------------------------------------------treesitter \/
{"nvim-treesitter/nvim-treesitter",
    build = ":TSUpdate",
    config = function ()
        local configs = require("nvim-treesitter.configs")

        configs.setup({
            ensure_installed = { "lua", "vim", "latex" },
            sync_install = false,
            highlight = { enable = true },
            indent = { enable = true},
        })
    end
},
------------------------------------------------------------------------------telescope \/
{ "nvim-telescope/telescope.nvim", 
    dependencies = {
        "nvim-lua/plenary.nvim",
    },
},
-------------------------------------------------------dependencies
    { "sharkdp/fd" }, { "BurntSushi/ripgrep" },
------------------------------------------------------------------------------lsp \/
{ "neovim/nvim-lspconfig",
  config = function()
    require('lspconfig').texlab.setup{}
  end
},
------------------------------------------------------------------------------telescope-fzf \/
{ "nvim-telescope/telescope-fzf-native.nvim", build = 'make' }
},
  -- Configure any other settings here. See the documentation for more details.
  -- colorscheme that will be used when installing plugins.
  install = { colorscheme = { "habamax" } },
  -- automatically check for plugin updates
  checker = { enabled = true },

-------------
})
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------other options

vim.cmd [[colorscheme moonfly]]

require('telescope').setup {
  extensions = {
    fzf = {
      fuzzy = true,                    -- false will only do exact matching
      override_generic_sorter = true,  -- override the generic sorter
      override_file_sorter = true,     -- override the file sorter
      case_mode = "smart_case",        -- or "ignore_case" or "respect_case"
                                       -- the default case_mode is "smart_case"
    }
  }
}
-- To get fzf loaded and working with telescope, you need to call
-- load_extension, somewhere after setup function:
require('telescope').load_extension('fzf')

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------configure nvim-cmp
lua = EOF
-- Set up nvim-cmp.
  local cmp = require'cmp'

  cmp.setup({
    snippet = {
      -- REQUIRED - you must specify a snippet engine
      expand = function(args)
        vim.fn["UltiSnips#Anon"](args.body) -- For `vsnip` users.
        -- require('luasnip').lsp_expand(args.body) -- For `luasnip` users.
        -- require('snippy').expand_snippet(args.body) -- For `snippy` users.
        -- vim.fn["UltiSnips#Anon"](args.body) -- For `ultisnips` users.
        -- vim.snippet.expand(args.body) -- For native neovim snippets (Neovim v0.10+)
      end,
    },
    window = {
      -- completion = cmp.config.window.bordered(),
      -- documentation = cmp.config.window.bordered(),
    },
    mapping = cmp.mapping.preset.insert({
      ['<C-b>'] = cmp.mapping.scroll_docs(-4),
      ['<C-f>'] = cmp.mapping.scroll_docs(4),
      ['<C-Space>'] = cmp.mapping.complete(),
      ['<C-e>'] = cmp.mapping.abort(),
      ['<CR>'] = cmp.mapping.confirm({ select = true }), -- Accept currently selected item. Set `select` to `false` to only confirm explicitly selected items.
    }),
    sources = cmp.config.sources({
      { name = 'nvim_lsp' },
      { name = 'ultisnips' }, -- For vsnip users.
      -- { name = 'luasnip' }, -- For luasnip users.
      -- { name = 'ultisnips' }, -- For ultisnips users.
      -- { name = 'snippy' }, -- For snippy users.
    }, {
      { name = 'buffer' },
    })
  })

  -- To use git you need to install the plugin petertriho/cmp-git and uncomment lines below
  -- Set configuration for specific filetype.
  --[[ cmp.setup.filetype('gitcommit', {
    sources = cmp.config.sources({
      { name = 'git' },
    }, {
      { name = 'buffer' },
    })
 })
 require("cmp_git").setup() ]]-- 

  -- Use buffer source for `/` and `?` (if you enabled `native_menu`, this won't work anymore).
  cmp.setup.cmdline({ '/', '?' }, {
    mapping = cmp.mapping.preset.cmdline(),
    sources = {
      { name = 'buffer' }
    }
  })

  -- Use cmdline & path source for ':' (if you enabled `native_menu`, this won't work anymore).
  cmp.setup.cmdline(':', {
    mapping = cmp.mapping.preset.cmdline(),
    sources = cmp.config.sources({
      { name = 'path' }
    }, {
      { name = 'cmdline' }
    }),
    matching = { disallow_symbol_nonprefix_matching = false }
  })

  -- Set up lspconfig.
  local capabilities = require('cmp_nvim_lsp').default_capabilities()
  -- Replace <YOUR_LSP_SERVER> with each lsp server you've enabled.
  require('lspconfig')['texlab'].setup {
    capabilities = capabilities
  }

---------------------------------------------------------------------------------ultisnips config
vim.g.UltiSnipsSnippetDirectories = { "~/.config/nvim/snippets" }
vim.g.UltiSnipsExpandOrJumpTrigger = "<tab>"
vim.g.UltiSnipsJumpBackwardTrigger = "<S-tab>"

Any help much appreciated.

"I am not a huge fan of the JavaScript dependency" - I feel obliged to warn you that this site has a JavaScript dependency.

:). I am referring to the node.js installation that is required.

Does it work if you rename your directory from snippets to something else like UltiSnips? It seems UltiSnips can parse SnipMate snippets and detects that based on the directory name, that might be the behavior you're seeing here

No... Ultisnips just doesn't work at all if I do that. In the Ultisnips docs it says it looks in the directory called "snippets"

I'm talking about vim.g.UltiSnipsSnippetDirectories, try to move that to ~/.config/nvim/UltiSnips and create that directory and move your snippets there, See also :help UltiSnips-how-snippets-are-loaded and this part in specific: https://github.com/SirVer/ultisnips/blob/49dc8cb2086db19d385791c8e1635723b0fd95c7/doc/UltiSnips.txt#L558-L560 Note that "snippets" is reserved for snipMate snippets and cannot be used in this list.

That (partly) did it. The error is not showing any more, but the tab stops are still not working. For example, if I try to use the first snippet in the file, and I type something in the \section{}, and when I press tab, it just inserts a tab (the space), rather than going to the next tabstop.

I suspect that you have a conflict with Tab and Shift Tab.
I would recommend to comment the two lines in your setup:
vim.g.UltiSnipsExpandOrJumpTrigger = "<tab>"
vim.g.UltiSnipsJumpBackwardTrigger = "<S-tab>"

I would use the default for Tab stop in UltiSnip are:

Ctrl J
Ctrl K

You can change that by setting:

g:UltiSnipsJumpForwardTrigger
g:UltiSnipsJumpBackwardTrigger

More information with: :help UltiSnips-trigger-key-mappings

Commenting out those 2 lines did not do it...same error

Same error but can you switch to the next entry using the <C-j> key and to the previous entry using the <C-k> key?
